# Can I deploy higher version process builder from sandbox to lower version in production?

Tags: deployment

I have a process builder with version8 in sandbox and want to deploy to prod which already having its version1.I have a doubt that will it deploy or not because another team deploy from sandbox to prod.

Comment: as long as you are using Metadata API V44+ it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy it to your prod using Ant tool, do not specify the version at the end of the process builder name in your package.xml. For example:

```
<types>
    <members>My_Process_Builder_Name</members>
    <name>Flow</name>
</types>
```

It will be deployed as version 2 on your prod org.

More details in the Flow Metadata API (v44) [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.216.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm)